# How to extract text from <input> tag using Selenium pageobject?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

How to extract text from  tag using Selenium pageobject?

This is the html code:

```
<div class="post-actions__body" style="display: block;">
  <span class="title">Reply from:</span>

<input class="account-input" value="" disabled="">

<textarea class="reply-text-area"></textarea>

<a class="btn-post-message btn--inactive" href="#">Post</a>

<!--<span class="character-count">63206</span>--></div>
```

I’m trying to extract text from the input tag: input class="account-input" value="" disabled="", the text (“account one”) is visible on the GUI.

This is how I define the pageobject:

```
div(:reply_account, :css => '.post-actions__body .account-input')
```

I’ve tried using reply_account_element.getText(), .getValue(), .getAttribute(), but none of them work. Please advise, thanks!

Comment: None of that HTML has "account one" in it. If its not in the HTML, then you can't extract it.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's the problem. So there is no way that I can extract it?

Comment: No...but assuming that its normal text, I'm guessing its somewhere in the HTML.  do a driver.getPageSource(), and then search that text for "account one".

Comment: I don't see "account one" there -> so *where is it*?

Comment: As it turns out, there is an error on the html code. I’m able to see "account one". Thanks everyone for his or her input!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
text(:reply_account, :class => 'account-input')

reply_account = 'some value'
puts reply_account #should print 'some value'
```

Honestly I would suggest asking for an ID for the tag if possible but that is more of a personal best practices sort of thing.